# render unbundled assets for admin user role

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bundle, bundling-and-minification

Is it possible for me to render unbundled and unminified scripts and styles for users in "Admin" role?

I've searched and found how to disable bundling

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = ...
```

and minification

```
foreach (Bundle bundle in bundles)
{
    bundle.Transforms.Clear();
}
```

in Global.asax.cs `Application_Start`, but I want this logic to be per-user, not per app instance, so it should not only be running on application start.

Comment: Just talking out of my hat, but what about an action filter?

Comment: Agree with @emodendroket, you definitely can set BundleTable.EnableOptimizations to true/false in the action filter.

Comment: Or maybe `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My implementation of emodendroket's suggestion, which is working well for me currently:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new DisableBundlingForAdminFilter());
        // other filters
    }

    private class DisableBundlingForAdminFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            #if !DEBUG
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = !filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Admin");
            #endif
        }
    }
}
```

`FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters` is called in `Application_Start`.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, None of the style or scripts included in the BundleConfig will be loaded unless it is included in the view by calling Scripts.Render() or Styles.Render() methods. By default  these methods are called from the _Layout.schtml page (Views/Shared).

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

Creating a different layout page for Admin area and loading the required scripts and styles will be a better option.

It is also possible to load these from any .cshtml file (view) using the same method, Scripts.Render(). In this case, it will be like,

```
@{
    if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        //Update this portion with path of required bundles
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    }
    else
    {
        //Update this portion with path of required bundles
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    }
}
```

The above snippet can be added either in _Layout page or any other page.

And if the requirement is to add any unbundled code. Just use the script tag. Which will look like this:

```
@{
    if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        //required script or style files
    }
    else
    {
        //To include unbundled and unminified scripts
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    }
}
```

Comment: I would not like to have to write these sorts of blocks everywhere that I use `@Scripts.Render` or `@Styles.Render`...not only would that involve touching way too many files, it would mean that I have to "manually" unbundle each bundle and maintain separate references for everything inside each one. Like if I remove a plugin from my jquery bundle, I'll have to chase down its reference in an admin block somewhere and remove that also.

Comment: You can include scripts and styles for Admin user in a single bundle and add this snippet in the _Layout.cshtml page so that you dont have to write it in every page.

I understood your question differently. I thought you wanted to include different scripts and styles for the admin user.

Comment: I see. It's actually that I want to serve the same assets throughout the site to admins and non-admins, just unbundled for admins. I have references to JS & CSS not only in my _Layout file, but also in many of my view files, so it doesn't suit my case to wrap each of them in an if-block. The single bundle approach doesn't work either, as I don't want (eg:) a jquery plugin for a homepage slider running on a different page dedicated to an Angular webapp, or vice versa.